# Override the chrome default shortcuts using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have application where I have to override few shortcuts keys of the chrome browser. I am not able to override few of the default shortkeys but can write few custom shortkeys to trigger a alert [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-m2txgu?file=index.html).

these are the new commands I want to override ,

- CTRL+T
- CTRL+N
- CTRL+W
- CTRL+F4
- CTRL+TAB
- Alt+F4

Is there any way I can override the chrome default shortcut keys.

Comment: actually, hmm.. those specific commands.. ight

Comment: wow.. the only way javascript made for us listening to the keyboard.. the event happens.. but i think the preventDefault can't be applied to it >:{ it's a good question

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown',
function(ev){
  //I just can't stop alt-F4 and CTRL-W though, think they are overrides you can't change, but for ones you can change, this works
  if(ev.ctrlKey||ev.altKey){ev.preventDefault()}
}
)
```

```html
<input placeholder="try copying/cutting/pasting :}" />
```

Comment: this is not working for me, can u please give me the working snippet , else you can edit the above example.

Comment: u can't copy, paste, cut, or select all at the least

Comment: @Santhosh for the other things.. im not sure they can be stopped *:shrugs:*